# bower install self_signed_cert_in_chain

Tags: security, ssl, installation, ssl-certificate, bower

I am building a angular app in windows, using git bash, so far I have been able to scaffold using yo, no issues, however when I am trying to issue the following command. Can someone please point me to resolve this issue.

bower install angular-bootstrap

I am getting the following error:

```
bower error         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-reso
urce failed: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Stack trace:
Error: Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-resource failed:
SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
    at createError (c:\Users\arusarka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\nod
e_modules\bower-registry-client\lib\util\createError.js:2:15)
    at Request._callback (c:\Users\arusarka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bow
er\node_modules\bower-registry-client\lib\lookup.js:97:29)
    at self.callback (c:\Users\arusarka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\n
ode_modules\request\request.js:129:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Request.request.emit (c:\Users\arusarka\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
bower\node_modules\bower-registry-client\node_modules\request-replay\index.js:69
:33)
    at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (c:\Users\arusarka\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\request\request.js:239:10)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1528:9)
    at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1368:19)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, and have not resolved it yet. But it's something to do with a network that's doing HTTPS interception. You should try BOWER-CANARY and see if you can turn off SSL from a ".bowerrc" file @user2839645

Comment: Hello, did I answer your question right? If yes, can you please mark it as an answer. Thank you. @user2839645

Answer (score 74):

It finally worked for me. These are the steps I took:

1. Uninstall bower from npm `npm uninstall bower` or `npm uninstall -g bower`
2. Install bower-canary from npm `npm install bower-canary` or `npm install -g bower-canary`
3. Create `.bowerrc` in your project directory with the following content to turn off SSL:

```js
{ "strict-ssl": false,  "https-proxy": "" }
```

4. Then try again `bower install angular-bootstrap`

Comment: How does bower-canary differ from regular bower?  More options? Bleeding edge?

Comment: It's pretty good and it works great, but it might not be as stable as the release version (even though I have not experienced any kind of issues). But, if you need to use not fully tested new functionalities (like strict-ssl), then you can use the canary version. @gdw2

Comment: This can be the 'Accepted Answer' !!

Comment: Also in my case it worked without uninstalling the bower. I also did not install bower-canary. Only adding the strict ssl false... line worked.

Comment: Adding the following line to .bowerrc is enough
    { "strict-ssl": false, "https-proxy": "" }

Comment: can confirm the only necessary step is #3

Answer (score 27):

Search for `.bowerrc` in your npm folder of Appdata, open the file and include the properties mentioned by natdico as follows:

```js
{
    "directory": "bower_components",
    "strict-ssl": false, 
    "https-proxy": ""
}
```

Comment: I wish this answer worked for me, as I would rather set this globally than at the project level, but unfortunately it did not work for me.  I had to update the project's `.bowerrc` as @natdico indicated.  I did want to point out though, if this worked for you, there are multiple `.bowerrc` files, located under different folders in `%APPDATA%` that correspond to the various project templates.  So you may want to do this for each.

Answer (score 17):

If you have access to the self-signed CA certificate that is part of your chain, you can add it to your `.bowerrc` file like so:

```json
{
  ...
  "ca": "/path/to/cacert.pem",
  ...
}
```

rather than disabling SSL, as other answers have suggested.

Disabling SSL will get you past this issue. However, doing so introduces the risk of creating some greater issues for yourself down the road.

> [documentation](https://bower.io/docs/config/) from Bower

Comment: This should be accepted answer IMO rather than switching off ssl because it's getting in the way.

Answer (score 1):

Add the lines below into your `.bowerrc` file in your project `directory`:

```
"strict-ssl": false,
 "https-proxy": "" .
```

your `.bowerrc` should look like this:

```
{
 "directory": "app/bower_components",
 "strict-ssl": false,
 "https-proxy": "" 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the registry config for npm by running the following command:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I tried and it worked for me.

Comment: This question is about bower not npm.